# How to link database record with drawable id?

Tags: android

In my android application I have categories that stored in categories table of database. And I want to assign icons for each category. 
Category table looks like:
[image: categories table]

The problem is that I am not able to use drawable constants that defined in R file because they are not static and will be changed from build to build. 

**Is it correct to create public.xml file and define all drawable constants inside the file?**

 I am afraid that I can override some android constants using this approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you simply use the **drawable names**?
You can **get the resource id at run time**, for the given resource name and type.

Add this method to your code:

```
protected final static int getResourceID
(final String resName, final String resType, final Context ctx)
{
    final int ResourceID =
        ctx.getResources().getIdentifier(resName, resType,
            ctx.getApplicationInfo().packageName);
    if (ResourceID == 0)
    {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException
        (
            "No resource string found with name " + resName
        );
    }
    else
    {
        return ResourceID;
    }
}
```

And use it like this:

```
int myID =
    getResourceID("your_resource_name", "drawable", getApplicationContext());
```

Note: no path nor extension, in case of images.

Comment: Thanks @Der Golem for you answer. And what about the performance of this solution ? I think that access to resource by id is faster than by name.

Comment: But you said that `The problem is that I am not able to use drawable constants that defined in R file because they are not static and will be changed from build to build.` - So, how would you solve that problem?

Comment: @Dear Golem I am looking for the solution. I thought that there is some way to define dwawable ids as constants.

Comment: You didn't get the point: **it's not possible**. Retrieving the ids at run-time is your **only** chance.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need this:

```
int imageResource = context.getResources().getIdentifier(imageName,
            "drawable", context.getPackageName());
```

and if you want to set the image to an imageView:

```
// set the image
if (imageResource != 0)
    yourImageView.setImageResource(imageResource);
```